# Make a visually better looking tree

Tags: ubuntu, tree

I am trying to visually show the tree structure of a directory. I know about the tree command and that works for me, but is there a program that takes the tree command output and makes it a bit more visually appealing? I understand that I could do this manually, but I was just wondering if there was software out that that would do this for me.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? Still text on a terminal? Or something else, like PDF?

Comment: Did you play around with the graphics options of `tree` already? I find `tree -AC` quite neat…

Comment: Looking to output it to something else (Like PDF). it is being sent to people that may not enjoy the nice terminal looking text. However I do like `tree -AC`

Comment: Something like https://gist.github.com/radixvinni/54087bdeeaf5fe99fa02 perhaps? (Never used it so not suggesting it in an answer. But I have used graphviz previously. Good tool.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how fancy you want to get, `tree` already can output directly to HTML format with the [`-H` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) (there are other options that affect the HTML output as well):

```
tree -H /path/to/directory /path/to/directory
```

You need to specify the path twice, because `-H` requires a root (it was designed around creating FTP directory pages.)

You can change the default fonts being used by modifying the CSS that is output. If you just want to globally modify the font used, you can get `sed` to do the job with a slightly hacky regex:

```
tree -H /path/to/directory /path/to/directory|sed "s/font-family : .*;/font-family : sans-serif;/"
```

(Disclaimer: this is subject to breakage if `tree` changes the boilerplate.)

If you need a PDF file from this, feel free to use your PDF converter of choice.